# How to attach an html file or docx file to ics file using javascript

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I am able to create this using sample text. the following is the code snippet

```
var icsMSG = ["BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\n" + attcament + "\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::test@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + Date.now() +"\nDTEND:" + Date.now() +"\nLOCATION:" + "hyd" + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR"];
var blobObject = new Blob(icsMSG,{ type: 'text/calendar' }); 
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.ics'); I tried the following way. But no luck. any ideas?  var attcament = "ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=smritta.docx:"+Base64.encode(messagesArr[i].getContent());
```

var icsMSG = ["BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\n" + attcament + "\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::Tamara1@testexch.local\nDTSTART:" + Date.now() +"\nDTEND:" + Date.now() +"\nLOCATION:" + "hyd" + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR"];
var blobObject = new Blob(icsMSG,{ type: 'text/calendar' }); 
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.ics');

Comment: @dmitry-streblechenko could you please have a look

Comment: I don't see any fields in the ics format that allow attachments.

Are you sure this is an actual thing?

Comment: I could find the following Attachment attr when I save ics file. BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:India Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=smritta.docx:UEsDBBQABgAIAAA
 AIQABLhqfkwEAABMGAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAA  But I need to attach file. Is there any way?@TerryCarmen

Comment: Here are the docs. It looks like a microsoft-specific extenion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624484(v=exchg.80).aspx so I wouldn't expect anything else to know how to handle it.